# Navigation Drawer Activity+RecyclerViewAdapter открыть новый фрейм (подробно о карточке)

Tags: android, activity, android-navigation-drawer, recyclerviewadapter

Используется Navigation Drawer Activity(создан с помощью среды Android Studio). Добавил на главный экран RecyclerView с карточками (CardView).
Не могу при нажатии на карточку открыть новый фрейм.

Библиотека:
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

код класса фрагмента:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

   public class AdvertDetails extends Fragment {
    ...
    }
```

Код адаптера RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    AdvertItem album = albumList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(album.title);
    holder.count.setText(album.price + " рублей");

    // loading album cover using Glide library
    Glide.with(mContext).load(album.thumbnail).into(holder.thumbnail);

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new AdvertDetails();
            FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();

        }
    });

}
```

Ошибка java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080033 (программ:id/container) for fragment AdvertDetails{31fef6 #1 id=0x7f080033}

Comment: Ошибку исправил. Оказывается в разметке XML случайно удалил android:id="@+id/container"